# Como resolver ou rejeitar uma Promise (nativa) em JavaScript fora do seu escopo?

Tags: javascript, promises

A maioria das implementações que vejo de Promises (promessas) em frameworks JavaScript trata o uso de Promises de maneira que é possível acessar as funções responsáveis pela rejeição e resolução em qualquer escopo.

Por exemplo, Angular:

```
var defer = $q();

setTimeout(function () {
    defer.resolve({status: true});
}, 5000);

defer.promise.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.status);
});
```

Algo similar é possível fazer no jQuery.

Porém, ao usar a `Promise` nativa do JavaScript, eu não consigo visualizar como poderia fazer tal operação, a não ser que a chamada se desse dentro do *callback* passado como argumento.

Para fazer no Javascript, eu teria que fazer assim, teoricamente:

```
 var p = new Promise(function (reject, resolve) {
        setTimeout(() => p({status: true}, 5000);
  });

  p.then((data) => console.log(data.status));
```

O meu questionamento é se existe alguma forma de fazer a mesma operação, usando o `Promise` nativo do JavaScript, da mesma forma que fiz no primeiro exemplo. Pois, dependendo da estrutura do projeto, poderia ser horrível ter que ficar refém de encapsular algo dentro de um *callback* para ter a funcionalidade da `Promise`. E pelo que andei pesquisando na internet, parece que a `Promise` do Javascript foi feita pra ser usada assim mesmo. :\

Existe alguma maneira *simples* de se burlar essa limitação da implementação de promessas do JavaScript?

Observação: Tentei usar a chamada `Promise.resolve(promise)`, mas não obtive o efeito desejado.

Comment: @WaIlaceMaxters, você deseja alguma informação adicional na resposta? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia fazer este tipo de gambiarra:

```js
const controls = {};
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  controls.resolve = resolve;
  controls.reject = reject;
});

promise.then((val) => {
  console.log('Fui resolvida. Valor de resolução:', val);
});

setTimeout(() => {
  controls.resolve(1);
}, 1000);
```

Esse tipo de código é possível já que a função executora (primeiro argumento passado para o construtor `Promise`) é executada de forma síncrona, o que permite "retirar" as funções `resolve` e `reject` de dentro do *callback*.

No entanto, o código acima pode ser considerado um *anti-pattern* (tanto é que o escondi por padrão) e, portanto, seu uso deve ser desencorajado. Por design, as `Promise`s foram arquitetadas para serem resolvidas somente através das funções (`resolve` e `reject`) passada para o executor. Desse modo, não é bem uma "limitação", mas sim uma escolha.

O construtor da `Promise` comporta-se dessa maneira por um motivo chamado *throw safety*. Isso significa que, se uma exceção for lançada de dentro do executor, o próprio construtor `Promise` capturará o erro e rejeitará imediatamente a `Promise`, sendo o valor de rejeição do próprio erro lançado. Isso é importante pois mantém um código previsível. <sub>[[Referência]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26150465/7445826)</sub>

Portanto, quando há a necessidade de se resolver uma "promessa" de fora de seu executor, vale mais a pena utilizar um *deffered*, que te permite fazer isso. A `Promise` do JavaScript não foi feita com esse *use-case* em mente. O jQuery, por exemplo, implementa o [`jQuery.Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/). Vale observar que *promises* e *deferreds*, embora possuam funções parecidas, não são a mesma coisa.

---

Vale notar que o método ("estático") [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) não é usado para resolver uma `Promise`, mas sim **criar** uma nova promessa, que será imediatamente resolvida com o valor passado como primeiro argumento de `Promise.resolve`. Existe também o método [`Promise.reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject), que se comporta de mesma maneira para criar uma promessa imediatamente rejeitada.

Não é o caso, mas se existisse um método `Promise.prototype.resolve`, esse sim seria usado para resolver *instâncias já existentes* de `Promise`.

Comment: Por que o negativo? Aliás, convido a pessoa que negativou postar uma outra resposta. :-)